# Problem importing a table containing dollar signs in pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots, external-files

I use pgfplot for plotting (obviously).
I load a table from a file, but I have the problem that my columns can have a dollar sign in them and then LaTeX complains:

> ! Extra }, or
>   forgotten $.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.5}

\def\myplot#1{
\foreach \file in {#1} {
        \begingroup
        \pgfplotstableread{\file}\report
        \pgfplotstableforeachcolumn \report \as {\colname}{ 
            \ifnum\pgfplotstablecol=0 %
            \else
    \begin{frame}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            title=\file,
            xlabel={Recall},
            ylabel={Precision},
            ymin=0,
            ymax=1,
            legend entries={\colname},
        ]

            \addplot table[ y = \colname] {\file};



        \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{frame}
    \fi
}
        \endgroup
    }
}

\begin{document}

\myplot{reports/report.csv}


\end{document}
```

Report.csv:

```
Recall  org/apache/tools/ant/helper/ProjectHelperImpl$ProjectHandler/results.json
0.0 1.0
0.1 0.5252788975806337
0.2 0.5242015649572856
0.30000000000000004 0.5212258417099329
0.4 0.5148570391086534
0.5 0.5132710775465511
0.6000000000000001  0.4835666797890683
0.7000000000000001  0.4736173712634098
0.8 0.4705726571519701
0.9 0.46958229692873316
1.0 0.46958229692873316
```

I tried using `\texttt`, but then it complains as well with a different message:

> ! Missing \endcsname
>   inserted.

It seems to me that I somehow need to escape the `$`, but how, seeing that I get them from a file?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: This is a shot in the dark, since you didn't post any [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) we could work on, but perhaps substituting `\expandafter\detokenize\colname` for `\texttt\colname` would solve the problem.

Comment: It would be great if you could edit your question and complete the code to form a complete minimal example document (starting from `\documentclass`, and including an example data file).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that the dollar sign opens math mode, but it's never closed. Since you only want to print the dollar sign, you'll somehow want to replace the `$` in the string with `\string$`.

You can do this [using the `xstring` package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39603/process-a-string-with-replacing-and-splitting) by writing `\StrSubstitute{\colname}{$}{\string$}[\stripped]`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.5}
\usepackage{xstring}


\def\myplot#1{
\foreach \file in {#1} {
        \begingroup
        \pgfplotstableread{\file}\report
        \pgfplotstableforeachcolumn \report \as {\colname}{ 
            \ifnum\pgfplotstablecol=0 %
            \else
            \StrSubstitute{\colname}{$}{\string$}[\stripped]
    \begin{frame}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            title=\file,
            xlabel={Recall},
            ylabel={Precision},
            ymin=0,
            ymax=1,
            legend entries={\stripped},
            legend style={font=\tiny,
                anchor=north,
                yshift=-8ex,
                at={(current axis.south)}},
        ]

            \addplot table[ y = \colname] {\report};


        \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{frame}
    \fi
}
        \endgroup
    }
}

\begin{document}

\myplot{report.csv}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Although your code solves the problem, I don't get any dollar sign in the caption when I compile it. I use PGF version: 2.10.

Comment: @Jubobs: Hm, that's strange. I'm using the TikZ CSV version, but I don't think it's an issue with that. Can you try using the `article` class (remove the `frame` environment for that) and printing the content of `\stripped` before the `tikzpicture`?

Comment: Just say `\StrSubstitute{\colname}{$}{\string$}[\stripped]`

Comment: @Jake sorry my bad, just ignore that last comment

Comment: @Jake I tried what you suggested, but the dollar sign is still missing in the expansion of `\stripped`. egreg's suggestion doesn't help. My TeX distribution is up to date. What's going on here?