# StrSubstitute not working nicely with pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots, legend, xstring

This question is related to my older question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119147/problem-importing-a-table-containing-dollar-signs-in-pgfplots), but now slightly different. I now have a function that is supposed to take two multivalued arguments. One contains the columns i want to plot. If i escape the dollar signs in my column names as in my previous question, trying to make a legend results in one legend entry containing the whole, comma-separated string. However, trying to do get around this like in the code sample below results in LaTeX complaining that \stripped is an undefined command sequence. What am i getting wrong?

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.5}

\def\multiplot#1 of #2{


    \begin{frame}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            title={Title},
            xlabel={Recall},
            ylabel={Precision},
            ymin=0,
            ymax=1,
            legend style={font=\tiny,
                anchor=north,
                yshift=-8ex,
                at={(current axis.south)}},
        ]
\foreach \fileRep in {#2} {
            \foreach \colname in {#1} {
            \addplot table[ y =\colname] {\fileRep};
    \StrSubstitute{\colname}{$}{\string$}[\stripped]
    \addlegendentry{\stripped}
    }
    }
        \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{frame}
}

\begin{document}

\multiplot{org/apache/tools/ant/helper/ProjectHelperImpl$ProjectHandler/results.json, org/apache/tools/ant/taskdefs/Javadoc$SourceFile/results.json} of {reports/report.csv}

\end{document}
```

Example file:

```
Recall  org/apache/tools/ant/helper/ProjectHelperImpl$ProjectHandler/results.json   org/apache/tools/ant/taskdefs/Javadoc$SourceFile/results.json
0   0.5 0.6
```

Comment: Could you please add a fragment of the `.csv` file for doing experiments?

Comment: ok i'll make something up, the headers are the important thing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have legend entries that are generated within a loop, you'll have to expand the content of the looping variable. You can do this simply by substituting `\addlegendentry` with `\addlegendentryexpanded`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.5}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{report.csv}
Recall  org/apache/tools/ant/helper/ProjectHelperImpl$ProjectHandler/results.json   org/apache/tools/ant/taskdefs/Javadoc$SourceFile/results.json
0   0.5 0.6
\end{filecontents}

\def\multiplot#1 of #2{


    \begin{frame}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            title={Title},
            xlabel={Recall},
            ylabel={Precision},
            ymin=0,
            ymax=1,
            legend style={font=\tiny,
                anchor=north,
                yshift=-8ex,
                at={(current axis.south)}},
        ]
\foreach \fileRep in {#2} {
            \foreach \colname in {#1} {
            \addplot table[ y =\colname] {\fileRep};
    \StrSubstitute{\colname}{$}{\string$}[\stripped]
    \addlegendentryexpanded{\stripped}
    }
    }
        \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{frame}
}

\begin{document}

\multiplot{org/apache/tools/ant/helper/ProjectHelperImpl$ProjectHandler/results.json, org/apache/tools/ant/taskdefs/Javadoc$SourceFile/results.json} of {report.csv}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It seems like i don't understand tex well as of yet - when are macros expanded and when not? Is the problem that \stripped is not expanded while in the loop, but he tries to expand it later on?

Comment: @kutschkem: Yes, exactly. PGFPlots is a bit "special" in this regard, because it doesn't expand things when they're first encountered, but rather it stores them first and then expands them when the axis is complete.